# Convert simple XML to Table in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to convert the following XML to table.

```
DECLARE @XMLToParse  XML;
SET @XMLToParse =   '<Employees>
                        <Senior>
                            <Emp>
                                Ravi
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Shanker
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Aditya
                            </Emp>
                        </Senior>
                        <Junior>
                            <Emp>
                                Roy
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Sham
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Divya
                            </Emp>
                        </Junior>
                      </Employees>';


DECLARE @ParsingTable  TABLE
    (Senior VARCHAR(100),Junior VARCHAR(100))

INSERT
INTO    @ParsingTable
    (Senior)
SELECT  xmlData.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Senior

FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('Employees/Senior/Emp') as xmlData(A)

select * from @ParsingTable
```

I'm trying to create the table as shown below :

```
Senior     Junior
-----------------
Ravi       Roy
Shanker    Sham
Aditya     Divya
```

The above code gives me the first column but I can't figure out how to insert the second col.

Comment: You have an issue.  What happens when there aren't the same number of Junior and Senor Employees.  The table should be two column : Rank (Junior or Senor), Employee Name.

Comment: @jdweng it's just a sample xml. Assume the same no. of junior and senior emp :)

Comment: You can't do what you want to because you would need to join the two objects, and there is no unique method of performing the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is lots of way to get your desired result one of them by using `cross apply` 
**METHOD1**

```
DECLARE @ParsingTable  TABLE
    (Senior VARCHAR(100),Junior VARCHAR(100))

INSERT
INTO    @ParsingTable
    (Senior,Junior)
SELECT  A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Senior,
        B.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Junior
FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('Employees/Senior/Emp') as xmlDataSenior(A) CROSS APPLY
        @XMLToParse.nodes('Employees/Junior/Emp') as xmlDataJunior(B)
```

**Note:** This will give you the duplicate records

**METHOD2:**
From this method you can only get one record ... For first record `[1]`,for second record `[2]` ,third records `[3]` and so on..............

```
SELECT  
    @XMLToParse.value('(Employees/Senior/Emp/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Senior,
    @XMLToParse.value('(Employees/Senior/Emp/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Junior
```

**METHOD3:** You can get your desired result by this trick

Make 2 Common Table Expression one for Senior and one for Junior with `Row_Number` and join these two `cte`s by row_number of first cte with second cte
Here is Your Complete Code

```
     DECLARE @XMLToParse  XML;
     SET @XMLToParse =   '<Employees>
                        <Senior>
                            <Emp>
                                Ravi
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Shanker
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Aditya
                            </Emp>
                        </Senior>
                        <Junior>
                            <Emp>
                                Roy
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Sham
                            </Emp>
                            <Emp>
                                Divya
                            </Emp>
                        </Junior>
                      </Employees>';


DECLARE @ParsingTable  TABLE
    (Senior VARCHAR(1000),Junior VARCHAR(100))


;with cte as
(
SELECT  A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Senior,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') DESC) AS SeniorRowNo

FROM    @XMLToParse.nodes('Employees/Senior/Emp') as xmlDataSenior(A)
)

 , cte2 as
 ( 
        SELECT  B.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Junior,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  B.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') DESC) AS JuniorRowNo
         FROM
        @XMLToParse.nodes('Employees/Junior/Emp') as xmlDataJunior(B)   
 )

 INSERT INTO    @ParsingTable(Senior,Junior)
 Select cte.Senior,cte2.Junior
 From cte inner join cte2 on cte.SeniorRowNo= cte2.JuniorRowNo
 select * from @ParsingTable
```

[**SQLFIDDLE METHOD 3**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/069bf/1)

**OUTPUT:**

```
  Senior     Junior
-----------------
Shanker    Sham
Ravi       Roy
Aditya     Divya
```

Comment: But seems like both the methods don't give the full desired result.

Comment: @iJade Check `SQL FIDDLE`

Answer (score 1):

Pivot looks like the obvious thing to do here but it requires some perhaps not so obvious XML queries to get a result set that you can do the pivot over.

```
select P.Senior, 
       P.Junior
from (
     select T1.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as ColumnName,
            T3.Value,
            T3.RowID
     from @XMLToParse.nodes('/Employees/*') as T1(X)
       cross apply (
                   select T2.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value,
                          row_number() over(order by T2.X) as RowID
                   from T1.X.nodes('Emp') as T2(X)
                   ) as T3
     ) as T
pivot (max(T.Value) for T.ColumnName in (Senior, Junior)) as P
```

The derived table that you pivot over looks like this:

```
ColumnName Value      RowID
---------- ---------- --------------------
Senior     Ravi       1
Senior     Shanker    2
Senior     Aditya     3
Junior     Roy        1
Junior     Sham       2
Junior     Divya      3
```

`RowID` is what is pairing the rows together.